# Sorting dates in ascending order from firebase to recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem in sorting the dates in ascending order to display in recyclerview

Here below is my database structure in firebase-realtime-database

```
{
firstitem : {
"name" : "first_item_name",
"date" : "29/11/2018",
"user" : "random user",
"url" : "My Url",
"tag" : "firstitem"
},
seconditem : {
"name" : "second_item_name",
"date" : "20/11/2018"
"user" : "another user",
"url"  : "a url",
"tag"  : "seconditem" 
 },  
 thirditem : {
 "name" : "third_item_name",
 "date" : "20/11/2017"
 "user" : "another user",
 "url"  : "a url",
 "tag"  : "thirditem"   
 }
 etc....
 }
```

By using the above structure i wants to display in ascending order according to dates, What query i should do to do this, Please a give me a solution to recover from this problem ,Thanks in advance.

```
Query MyEventsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Workers Details").child(userID)
            .child("My Events").orderByChild("From_Date");

    //Display events
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<WorkerMyEvents> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<WorkerMyEvents>()
                    .setQuery(MyEventsRef, WorkerMyEvents.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkerMyEvents, WorkerMyEventViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkerMyEvents, WorkerMyEventViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WorkerMyEventViewHolder eventsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final WorkerMyEvents newEvents)
        {
            //Id with date and time key
            final String IDs = getRef(i).getKey();
            final String eventIDs = IDs.substring(0,18);

            final String serve = list3.get(i);

            NewEventsRef.child(eventIDs).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
```

Comment: What have you tied so far?

Comment: I used orderbychild() query , but it considering only 1st two letters of date ,but not considered month and year.

Comment: Add that code to your question and tell what doesn't work the way to expect.

Comment: Could you say your own suggestion or idea to obtain that task which i asked?

Comment: I want to display the events from database ,queried by dates in ascending order.

Comment: I understand but show us what you have tried, to see what's wrong.

Comment: The database structure is different, but the concept is same which is asked, I uploaded the code with query , by using this i can sort based on only 1st 2 letters of date but not the whole date.